# Meta tags para Redes Sociais

Tags: html, facebook, twitter-api, google-plus, html-meta-tag

Nós sabemos que é necessário a implementação de meta tags especificas no `<head>` dos nossos sites para optimizar a partilha de conteúdo nas redes sociais como o **Twitter, Google+, Pinterest e Facebook**.

Para isso é necessário definir como é que os atributos - título, descrição, imagens e outros serão apresentados nas redes sociais, fazendo uso das mesmas.

Mas quais são as meta tags necessárias a ser implementadas para estas redes sociais mencionadas acima?

Como por exemplo, para o Facebook, nós utilizamos as `og:meta` tags como no exemplo abaixo, mas e quanto às outras?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Titulo">
<meta property="og:description" content="Descrição aqui">
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Saber exatamente quais as meta tags das redes sociais a ser incluídas pode ser confuso, até mesmo para webmasters experientes.
Existe uma variedade de estruturas a considerar, suportadas pela maioria das plataformas sociais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- [**Twitter Cards**](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview): Sumários, Imagens, Galerias, Apps, Video, Audio, e Produtos
- [**Pinterest Rich Pins**](https://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins_overview/): Produtos, Receitas, Filmes, e Artigos
- [**Google+**](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/): Artigos, Blog, Livro, Evento, Negócio Local, Organização, Pesoa, Produto, e Revisões/Avaliações
- [**Facebook**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph): Artigos, Fotos, Audio, Video, e mais

Para ajudar a facilitar isto, vamos criar aqui uma variedade de modelos exemplares que se adaptam para diversas necessidades.

### Como usar estes modelos

Para usar estes modelos, basta copiar e colar um dos modelos para o `<head>` do seu website usando o seu editor de texto preferido à sua escolha. Certifique-se de substituir qualquer texto dentro da tag `<title>` e dos atributos `content=" "` com os seus próprios dados, e personalizar, eliminar ou adicionar todas as tags que você achar necessário.

> **Atênção**: Não remova ou substitua os atributos `content="article"` e `content="product"` pois estes são usados para informar à
>   plataforma social se este conteúdo é um `artigo` ou um `produto`

Os três primeiros modelos são otimizados para o típico uso do texto de marcação e de dados `"article (artigo)"`, ideal para publicações de Blogs e conteúdo escrito. O modelo final contém markup para páginas de produtos.

### Modelo minimalista

Esta versão simplificada corre de forma leve e rápida. Ela contém o mínimo de dados para compartilhamento otimizado através do Twitter, Facebook, Google+ e Pinterest.

As tags `<title>` e `descrições meta` estão incluídas, embora tecnicamente elas não sejam meta tags de redes sociais. Isto é porque elas também podem ser utilizadas pelo Google+ e outras plataformas de redes sociais, e é uma boa prática incluí-las em todas as páginas que você publicar.

```html
<!-- Coloque estes dados entre as tags <head> do seu site -->
<title>Título da página. O comprimento máximo é de 60-70 caracteres</title>
<meta name="description" content="Descrição da página. Não pode conter mais do que 155 caracteres." />

<!-- Twitter Card data -->
<meta name="twitter:card" value="Sumário">

<!-- Open Graph data -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Titulo aqui" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Descrição aqui" />
```

### Modelo Padrão

O modelo padrão representa uma implementação mais robusta das `meta tags sociais` e é suposto funcionar em todas as plataformas. Para além de todas as características do modelo minimalista acima, o modelo padrão inclui o seguinte:

- O cartão básico do Twitter - Twitter Summary card
- Imagem de miniatura no Twitter
- Página no Facebook Insights

```html
<!-- Coloque estes dados entre as tags <head> do seu site -->
<title>Título da página. O comprimento máximo é de 60-70 caracteres</title>
<meta name="description" content="Descrição da página. Não pode conter mais do que 155 caracteres." />

<!-- Twitter Card data -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="Sumário">
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@nome_do_publicador">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Título da página">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Descrição da página, menos do que 200 caracteres.">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@nome_do_autor">
<!-- Imagem Twitter Summary Card, tem que ter pelo menos 120x120px -->
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">

<!-- Open Graph data -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Titulo aqui" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Descrição aqui" /> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Nome do site, ex: Stackoverflow" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="ID numérico de cada usuário Facebook, separado por virgulas." />
```

### O Modelo Completo

Este é o monstro! Para além de conter todos os dados contidos no modelo padrão, o modelo completo contém:

- **Google Authorship** e **Publisher Markup**. No entanto estes dados não mudam a aparência do seu conteúdo no Google+, mas poderá potencialmente adicionar links para as suas páginas do Google+ em resultados de pesquisa.
- Markup (marcação) Schema.org para artigos
- Twitter Summary Card com imagem grande
- Expandir dados Open Graph para artigos

```html
<!-- Atualize a sua tag <html> para incluir os atributos itemscope e itemtype. -->
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

<!-- Coloque estes dados entre as tags <head> do seu site -->
<title>Título da página. O comprimento máximo é de 60-70 caracteres</title>
<meta name="description" content="Descrição da página. Não pode conter mais do que 155 caracteres" />

<!-- Schema.org markup para Google+ -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="O Nome ou Título aqui">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Isto é a descrição da página">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">

<!-- Twitter Card data -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="sumário_image_grande">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@nome_do_publicador">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Título da página">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Descrição da página, menos do que 200 caracteres.">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@nome_do_autor">
<!-- Twitter Summary Card com imagem larga, tem que ter pelo menos 280x150px -->
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://www.example.com/image.html">

<!-- Open Graph data -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Titulo aqui" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Descrição aqui" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Nome do site, ex: Stackoverflow" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2013-09-17T05:59:00+01:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2013-09-16T19:08:47+01:00" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Secção do Artigo" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Tag do Artigo" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="ID numérico de cada usuário Facebook, separado por virgulas." />
```

Para implementação do Google Authorship, visite a página: [**The Usual Searchspects**](http://www.iacquire.com/blog/18-meta-tags-every-webpage-should-have-in-2013), na secção - **Authorship Markup**, para implementa-lo à sua preferência

### E por fim, o Modelo Produto

```html
<!-- Atualize a sua tag <html> para incluir os atributos itemscope e itemtype. -->
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

<!-- Coloque estes dados entre as tags <head> do seu site -->
<title>Título da página. O comprimento máximo é de 60-70 caracteres</title>
<meta name="description" content="Descrição da página. Não pode conter mais do que 155 caracteres" />

<!-- Schema.org markup para Google+ -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="O Nome ou Título aqui">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Isto é a descrição da página">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">

<!-- Twitter Card data -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="product">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@nome_do_publicador">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Título da página">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Descrição da página, menos do que 200 caracteres.">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@nome_do_autor">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.example.com/image.html">
<meta name="twitter:data1" content="$3">
<meta name="twitter:label1" content="Preço">
<meta name="twitter:data2" content="Preto">
<meta name="twitter:label2" content="Cor">

<!-- Open Graph data -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Titulo aqui" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Descrição aqui" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Nome do site, ex: Stackoverflow" />
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="15.00" />
<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD" />
```

---

### Ferramentas para testes e aprovação

> Twitter Validation Tool
>   **https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator**
>
> Facebook Debugger
>   **https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug**
>
> Google Structured Data Testing Tool
>   **http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets**
>
> Pinterest Rich Pins Validator
>   **http://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins/validator/**

<sub>Mais informações sobre este tópico em: [Tags Every Webpage Should Have](http://www.iacquire.com/blog/18-meta-tags-every-webpage-should-have-in-2013)</sub>

Comment: Muito legal compartilhar isto Chun +1

Comment: Chun, eu devo usar essas tags apenas na páginas index ou em todas as que são abertas (sem autenticação)? Por exemplo, uma página de manual, ou faq, vale a pena criar também o modelo completo?

Comment: Sim @gustavox , se quiser que essas páginas também sejam partilhadas devidamente tem que incluir o código nessas páginas também para que os dados/informação possam ser extraídos pelas redes sociais corretamente (não se esqueça de mudar os dados das `meta-tags` consoante cada página).

Comment: Muito bom, parabéns. +1

Comment: Parabéns, muito útil.