# HTML Js Share compartilhar conteúdo

Tags: javascript, html5, facebook, twitter-api

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma solução global para gerar o compartilhamento de notícias em um portal de conteúdo em redes sociais. Ou eu tenho que inserir um meta tag diferente para cada rede social em cada página. (Facebook, Twitter e G+)

> Cenário:
>   O usuário clica em um botão para compartilhar uma notícia.
>
> Problema: Devo gerar cabeçalho metatag diferente para cada rede social
>   a se compartilhar? são apis diferentes? existe algo que gere isso
>   automatico para cada rede social escolhida?

Comment: Davi, se existe ou não uma solução global eu não sei, mas acredito que não, logo é necessário criar um metatag p/ cada rede social, com certeza são apis diferentes e algo que gere automático ou não depende da rede social, mas acredito que não todas precisam de uma config. prévia, todas as vezes que fiz implementei tive que configurar, aqui tem algo bem interessante sobre metatags:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72860/meta-tags-para-redes-sociais?rq=1

Comment: Muito boa esta recomendação. Uma outra dúvida é: as metatags necessariamente precisam estar no <head> ou posso passar ela por parametro por exemplo?

Comment: Sim elas precisam estar no <head>, Note: <meta> tags always go inside the <head> element. Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp sobre a questão de passar por parâmetro, depende de o que tu quer fazer, como tu quer fazer, mas não to conseguindo imaginar uma situação que isso seria necessário.

Comment: A situação é uma lista com 50 notícias em uma única página. Logo o <head> ficaria imenso se tivesse que criar para cada notícia um conjunto de head. Eu queria em cada botao ja gerar algo simples para compartilhar sem precisar das tags no header.